# How to know if string is empty in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh

```
function export_if_empty {
    [[ -z "$1" ]] && declare -gx "${1}"="$2"
}
export_if_empty 'XDG_CONFIG_HOME'   "$HOME/.config"
export_if_empty 'XDG_DATA_HOME'     "$HOME/.local/share"
export_if_empty 'XDG_CACHE_HOME'    "$HOME/.cache"
export_if_empty 'XDG_DATA_DIRS'     '/usr/share:/usr/local/share'
export_if_empty 'XDG_CONFIG_DIRS'   '/etc/xdg'
unset -f export_if_empty
```

This does not work. even if the XDG_CONFIG_HOME is empty, -z flag fails to correctly identify it

[Please check this image to know what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDsQF.png)

Comment: You never pass an empty $1 to your script. Call your script with `export_if_empty '' JustATest`, and you will see that the `-z` test is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are testing the string `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` itself, not the value of the variable named `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`. You need indirect parameter expansion

```
[[ -z "${(P)1}" ]] && declare -gx "$1=$2"
```

The `(P)` flag specifies the value of the parameter be use as the name of another variable to expand, for example:

```
$ foo=bar bar=3
$ echo $foo
bar
$ echo ${(P)foo}
3
```

Comment: Thanks was banging my head to figure this out.